# How do you craft a Pain au Chocolat?

Tags: candy-box-2

I need some Pains au Chocolat to increase my stats in the wishing well. How do you craft a Pain au Chocolat in Candy Box 2?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go in [The Castle](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/The_Castle), in the big room in the middle. There, talk to the furnace, and give him a hundred candies and a chocolate bar. Then you will get a pain au chocolat.

You can make as many Pains au Chocolat as you wish there, as long you have enough chocolate bars.

You can also use [The Computer](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/The_Computer) if you have it, and use the following command:

```
add (Quantity) painsauchocolat
```